# why does python require the preservation of the order in multiple inheritance?

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

Python now uses c3 linearization method to determine the method resolution order (MRO). The MRO needs to be consistent with the local multiple-inheritance order. The algorithm adds a local parents list to check the consistency. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization)

My question is, why do we need this feature? What are the advantages of doing so?

For example:

```
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
class C(A,B):
    pass               # failed because of inconsistent mro
class C(B,A):
    pass               # passed
```

Why don't we treat C(A,B) just in the same way as C(B,A)?

Comment: What if both `A` and `B` implement the same methods? How would you resolve the conflict?

Comment: @norok2 You would resolve it according to the MRO. The question comes down to, what *should* the MRO look like, and why is `[C, B, A, object]` more desirable than `[C, A, B, object]`?

Comment: The linked article provides the three criteria, all of which cannot be met if you use `class C(B, A)`. Are you asking why failing to meet those criteria is bad?

Comment: @chepner Yes, I just want to know why do we set this criterion.